# I don't know how to deploy this

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, deployment

I'm relatively new to StackOverflow and deploying. So be patient if this isn't the place to ask about this, any kind of help will be truly appreciated.

The thing is, I have a web app with a Front End made with **ReactJS**, a Backend with **Node and Express**, and backed up by **MongoDB**.

The app is a bit simple, you can login/logout, post photos/gifs, have your own profile etc.

As of now, My React app communicates to the backend with a Proxy, the images are a static folder served by express (so that its easy to fetch the images on react), and so far the tests went good, I set up Mongo Atlas so that I don't have to worry about that in production.

**The point is...** I don't know exactly where or how should I deploy this, I'm considering using Heroku but since I don't know if it supports local storing, and  I'm not sure if it'll work, same for Netlify. I've been thinking of composing up docker images, renting hosting on Linode and deploy the images there.
So far my project tree looks like this

```
Project -> .git
           client->React Stuff
           server->Node Stuff + Images folder 
           //each with their own package.json and configs/env
```

If you have a document or a video that would help me know about deployment, I'll really appreciate, and also if you think that I should use Heroku/Netlify/etc or just wanna leave a msg , please do so!, tyvm in advance

Comment: I have used same structure in one of my test project but instead of using proxy, I used whole URL because i think after react build it will not have whole server URL so I wont be able to deploy server and client on different servers so in that case you'll have to build react and copy react build inside express public folder and in express use `/` route to return static files from public folder.

Answer (score 0):

From what you mentioned it sounds like Heroku should do the trick. Heroku uses git to store files. 
[Here's](https://medium.com/@hectorohernz/creating-a-mern-application-with-deployment-to-heroku-2020-beginner-part-1-be25148e3df9) a guide that should help you set it up